# Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to save/persist multiple objects from a collection to a DB but i keep getting error. I have debugged and found out that this issue come when i try to save product.
This exception comes on my ec2 instance server on my local workspace/machine.

ERORR:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy137.findOne(Unknown Source)
```

Persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    version="2.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
                
            <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; 
            value="update" to modify an existing database; 
            value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; 
            value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
            
            <property name="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy" value="com.canland.business.annotations.PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl"/>
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl" />  -->
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer" value="allow"/> -->
            
            
             <property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix" value="_aud"/>
             <property name="org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete" value="true"/>
             <!-- <property name="org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name" value="rev"/>
             <property name="org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name" value="revtype"/>
             <property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy" value="org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy"/>
             <property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_end_rev_field_name" value="AUDIT_REVISION_END"/>
             <property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_store_revend_timestamp" value="true"/>
             <property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_revend_timestamp_field_name" value="AUDIT_REVISION_END_TS"/> -->
                        
            <!-- Uncomment the following two  properties     for JBoss only -->
           <!--  <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false"/>-->
            
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-insert"
                value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostInsertEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-update"
                value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-delete"
                value="org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostDeleteEventListener,org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-update"
                value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.pre-collection-remove"
                value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.event.post-collection-recreate"
                value="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />  -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Code to Save a collection :

```
@Autowired
private Prodservice prodservice;

public saveValue(List<Product> products){
   for(Product p : products){
    p.setSomething("");
    prodservice.saveIteratedProduct(p);
   }
}
```

ProdService.class:  method

```
@Autowired
private ProductRepository productRepository
saveIteratedProduct(Product p){
        Product product = null;
            try {               
                product = productRepository.save(p);                        
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return product;
}
```

I am using simple JpaRespostitory to save the data in my repositories.

Comment: who is downloadProduct in `product = productRepository.save(downloadProduct);` ?

Comment: @tremendous7  I have changed the entity name for save method, 'downloadproduct' was a typo.

Comment: do you have any particular annotations on ProduceRepository interface?

Comment: @tremendous7 just the basic @-Repository  annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue, the issue was with the hibernate itself, i am using 5.2.1 and this issue was fixed in 5.3

I updated my hibernate maven dependency to 5.3.0 and the issue

[See here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13076) for the fix